# Execute program with relative path and 'PATH' environment in Bash shell

Tags: bash, mingw

**Bash Environment**

Given a very simple disk structure as below

[image: Simple File Structure]

And environment path variable set to dir1 and dir2 as below

```
$ env|grep PATH
 returns :-
 PATH=/:/usr/bin:/e/path/to/directory/dir1:/e/path/to/directory/dir2
```

execution of the program fails as below

```
$ bin/prog.exe
bash: bin/prog1.exe: No such file or directory
```

or also

```
$ /bin/prog1.exe
bash: /bin/prog.exe: No such file or directory
```

however if we modify path to include /bin

```
PATH=/:/usr/bin:/e/path/to/directory/dir1/bin:/e/path/to/directory/dir2/bin
```

it does of course work

```
$ prog1.exe

Hello from prog1 ...
```

My question is how do I make paths relative to 'environment' PATH work in bash?

In practise I am given some files that have 10's of relative paths generated to many different virtual root locations, to which I cant change.

It is also not possible to use a full path, or just the executable name of (which we know works) for this scenario.

Comment: Sorry image shows as directory but on the system it is dir1 and 2

Comment: correct image now

Comment: There is no real reason to add `/` to your path. There shouldn't be any executable programs at the root of the file system.

Comment: Removed the makefile tag that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Of course your all right - just having a brain freeze moment - many thanks

Answer (score 3):

See `man bash` for explanation (emphasis mine):

> If the name is neither a shell function nor a builtin, and **contains no slashes**, bash searches  each  element of the PATH for a directory containing an executable file by that name.

Comment: Of course your all right - just having a brain freeze moment - many thanks

Answer (score 2):

As @choroba implies, you can't do what you're asking to do.

If you need to find a program in a subdirectory of one of the entries in your PATH, you'll have to iterate until you find it:

```
rel_path="bin/prog.exe"
IFS=: read -ra paths <<<"$PATH"
for path in "${paths[@]}"; do
    if [[ -x "$path/$rel_path" ]]; then
        exe="$path/$rel_path"
        break
    fi
done
if [[ -z "$exe" ]]; then
    echo "cannot find $rel_path"
else
    echo "found $rel_path as $exe"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as relative path lookup. If your command name contains any `/` characters, it is treated as a path relative to your current working directory only. If it has no `/` characters, then the shell will look only in the exact directories, not any subdirectories under them, listed in your `PATH`.

Relative path lookups would raise a host of issues related to order in which subdirectories should be searched.